# How can I programmatically change the Page Header height in a RDLC report?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reporting, rdlc

Does anyone know of a way to change the height of a Page Header in a RDLC report?  I have a textbox that has line breaks and would like the height of the Page Header to expand if there are more than one line.  Does anyone know how to do this?  Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A RDLC file is basically an XML file. If you first change the value of the XML node: Report \ PageHeader \ Height and afterwards you load the report definition in the Report Viewer control you can dynamically change the header height (and pretty much anything else, as long as you leave a valid XML behind). You can use the XmlDocument class to perform these operations.